# Missing cookies during login using Flurl

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, .net-core, flurl

Somehow some of the cookies are missing when I'm trying to login to a web service. Three parts of the cookie are missing, specifically the token and refresh-token. However when I try logging in using Postman I get all parts of the cookie. Which is very strange, below you can see my code for logging in to the service using Flurl.

```
private async Task<IFlurlClient> GetClientAsync()
{
    var client = new FlurlClient(BaseUrl).EnableCookies();
    var login = await client.Request("/Account/LogOn")
                            .AllowAnyHttpStatus()
                            .PostUrlEncodedAsync(new { Login = credentials.Username, credentials.Password});

    if (!login.IsSuccessStatusCode) throw new ResponseException("Login failed");
    return client;
}
```

See screenshot for the cookies I can see when debugging.

[image: image of debug cookies]

Next we can see which cookies I can see when I use Postman.

[image: image of postman cookies]

I need all 7 cookies for subsequent calls to the service. Any idea on what I might be doing wrong or what could be missing?

When using Postman all I do is a simple POST with form-data using the credentials I have. Both the calls, Postman and Flurl, succeed with a status code 200 OK, all that differs are the received cookie values.

Comment: If possible, please try this in the latest 3.0 prerelease. You'll have to work through the breaking changes to cookies but it's a much better experience and you'll likely want to migrate to it eventually anyway: https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/506

Comment: @ToddMenier From the legend himself, thank you! Updating to 3.0 and using CookieSession actually solved everything and made the code cleaner. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Todd I solved my issue by updating to Flurl 3.0 and updated my code. See below for the new and improved version using CookieSession.

```
private async Task<CookieJar> GetCookiesAsync()
{
    using var session = new CookieSession(Endpoint);
    var data = new {credentials.Username, credentials.Password};

    var login = await session.Request("/login").AllowAnyHttpStatus().PostUrlEncodedAsync(data);
    return login.ResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode ? session.Cookies : null;
}

...

var cookies = await GetCookiesAsync();
if (cookies == null) return false;

var test = await Endpoint.AppendPathSegment("/test")
                         .WithCookies(cookies)
                         .AllowAnyHttpStatus()
                         .PostAsync(null);

var success = test.ResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode;
```

Using this I could pass the cookies received when logging in to any subsequent calls and everything worked just as it should.

Edit:

Updated code again to use Todds suggestion, see below.

```
private async Task<CookieSession> CreateSessionAsync()
{
    using var session = new CookieSession(Endpoint);   
    var data = new {credentials.Username, credentials.Password};

    var login = await session.Request("/login").AllowAnyHttpStatus().PostUrlEncodedAsync(data);
    return login.ResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode ? session : null;
}

var session = await CreateSessionAsync();
if (session == null) return false;

var test = await session.Request("/test")
                        .AllowAnyHttpStatus()
                        .PostJsonAsync(new {});

return test.ResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode;
```

Once again, thank you so much Todd! This solution is working wonders in production at the moment.

Comment: Awesome! It's all very new so it's great to see it working in a real-world scenario. One minor suggestion is that you could return the `CookieSession` from your helper method rather than the `CookieJar`. The point of `CookieSession` is that don't need to call `WithCookies` on subsequent calls. In this case you can just take that returned session and do `session.Request("/test")...` without having to attach the cookies explicitly.